# How to redirect from an Angular component markup to its definition in Visual Studio?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way while in an html file in Visual Studio editor to click on an Angular component tag and it redirects me to its definition in the .ts file?

Answer (score -1):

It is suggested to code Angular apps in Visual Studio Code (Not Visual studio) IDE
There it works by default and even better when you install Angular plugins.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core with Angular and VS is my IDE. I don't want to use VS Code. This should be a comment instead of an answer as it does not answer the question.

Comment: I am also fullstack dev and I use VS for back-end .NET , but I use VS Code for front-end Angular because it's better suited also based on official microsoft documentation. I'm not shy to use two IDEs ...

Comment: I use WebStorm which can navigate in Angular. I still want to use a single IDE.